# Convert local url to type of data and upload to a server swift

Tags: swift, swiftui

How do I capture the `previewURL` data so I can upload it to my server?

In other words, my goal is to take the local file url

```
@Published var previewURL: URL?
// file://123-123-123.mov
```

then convert it to a `Data` type:

```
@Published var movieData = Data(count: 0)
```

and then upload it to my AWS server

```
   func saveVideo() async {
        
        let uploadUrl = URL(string: postUploadData.url!)!
        var requestToUpload = URLRequest(url: uploadUrl)
        requestToUpload.httpMethod = "PUT"

        requestToUpload.httpBody = self.movieData
        do {
            let (data, _) = try! await URLSession.shared.data(for: requestToUpload)
  
        } catch {
            debugPrint("Error loading \(url): \(String(describing: error))")
        }
   
    }
```

Here is the callback when I finish recording the video:

```
func fileOutput(_ output: AVCaptureFileOutput, didFinishRecordingTo outputFileURL: URL, from connections: [AVCaptureConnection], error: Error?) {
        if let error = error {
            print("FILE OUTPUT ERROR ----->", error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        
        // CREATED SUCCESSFULLY
       
        self.recordedURLs.append(outputFileURL)
        

        self.previewURL = outputFileURL
   
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this code in the `fileOutput` function:

```
let data = try Data(contentsOf: self.previewURL!)
    print("DATA FOR MOVIE FILE ----->", data)    
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't load the whole movie data to memory. This will crash you app if the movie size is too big.

Comment: @LeoDabus how would you recommend to this?